# I'm new to coding and I've ran into the error "module 'wolframalpha' has no attribute 'Client' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

I don't know what went wrong and I'm not sure if I installed all the plugins I needed or if my code is just wrong

```
import wolframalphaclient = wolframalpha.Client("My App API")app_id = 'My App API'  res = client.query('temperature in Washington, DC on October 3, 2012')print (res)
```

[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZMTWBpLUa4) was a youtube video I was copying and

[here's](http:////https://www.wolframalpha.com/) the link to the website if you need it also

Comment: could you please format your code properly. Also the link to the website is broken please fix that. Also could you please paste the exact error and stack trace so that we may be able to help you properly.

Comment: Don't use an equal sign after an import: `import wolframalphaclient = wolframalpha.Client("My App API")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your coding style. Copy and paste following code line by line see if this solves your problem:

```
import wolframalpha

client = wolframalpha.Client("lilpumpsaysnopeeking")
```

this should solve your problem. And one more thing use their `github` for the code:
[PyDa.py](https://gist.github.com/KhanradCoder/7886acf1a51d8635ec2ab09f81de6268)